# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cot(\frac{x}{2^n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$

Can L' Hopital's rule be used to solve this? And differentiate it with respect to $x$ or $n$?

What I've found is that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)}
\end{equation}

which is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, but I don't know how to go further from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it was supposed to be $n$, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x =1.
$$

Comment: is the solution $\frac{2}{x}$?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle \varepsilon=\frac{x}{2^{n}}$ and applying L'Hospital's rule,

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\cot \frac{x}{2^{n}}}{2^{n-1}}  &=
  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{2\varepsilon}{x\tan \varepsilon} \\ &=
  \lim_{\varepsilon \to \infty} \frac{2}{x\sec^{2} \varepsilon} \\ &=
  \frac{2}{x}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Try this- We know that $\lim_{x \to \ 0}$$ \text{tan}(x)\over x$$ = 1$ Now, $\text{cot}(\frac{x}{2^n})$= $2^n\over x$ , Then the answer is $2\over x$. You can use the L'Hopital's rule but it just gets harder.

Comment: This limit formula doesn't mean anything.

Comment: You did the same thing as me and say that I am wrong.... well, I should still upvote your answer as it is expressed better.

Comment: What in the world does the formula $$\lim_{x\to0}\tan (x)=x$$ even mean?

Comment: It means in english- "tan(x) approaches x as x approaches 0"

Comment: @WinVineeth Oh I know that. But the right side of the equality includes $x$, while the left side sends $x$ to $0$... What I am saying is that the equation is wrong.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that a limit  when $x$ tends to some value can't be expressed with $x$. Btw,  I didn't downvote your answer – just waiting it to  be correctly phrased.

Comment: @5xum It's just a way of expression. It's not strictly mathematical. That's y I said Bernard expressed it better in my previous comment.

Comment: @WinVineeth No, the problem is not the "not strictly mathematical", the problem is that the equation you wrote down is **wrong**. I see now you fixed it. I don't mind you saying "$\tan x \approx x$ as $x\to 0$", but writing down the equation you wrote down is simply false.

Answer (score 0):

It is so much simpler to rewrite it as $\;2^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\tan\dfrac{x}{2^n}}$, and use *equivalents*:
$$\tan u\sim_0 u,\quad\text{hence}\quad \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cot\Bigl(\frac{x}{2^n}\Bigr) \sim_\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\frac{1}{\dfrac{x}{2^n}}=\frac 2x.$$

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can as well compute
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{t}\cot\frac{x}{t}
$$
because if this limit exists, also your sequence converges at the same limit as $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n=\infty$.

Now you can use substitutions more freely: use $u=x/t$, so you get (for $x>0$)
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{2}{x}\frac{u}{\tan u}=\frac{2}{x}
$$
For $x<0$ the limit is for $t\to0^-$, but the final value is the same.